# raw buffer to Eigen::Map::Matrix of complex

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm getting a raw buffer stream in from a source.

```
unsigned char *data = ...; // of know length
```

I would like to map that into MyMapMatrixXci.

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<uint16_t>, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>
    MyMatrixXci;
typedef Eigen::Map<MyMatrixXci> MyMapMatrixXci;
```

I'm struggling to find the right steps to get this mapped.

If I already have my data in a type matching the map I can get things to work.  Example below...

```
std::complex<uint16_t> *data = new std::complex<uint16_t>[rows * cols];
for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; ++i) {
    data[i] = {i, i};
}
Eigen::Map<MyMatrixXci, Eigen::RowMajor> mat(&data[0], rows, cols);
std::cout << mat << std::endl;
```

Where I'm struggling is reinterpreted casting of the 'unsigned char *data' buffer to the 'std::complex<uint16_> *'.  Or going directly to the Map.  In the casting case I always end up in a cast 'not allowed' error.  In the direct case I end up on not matching a candidate constructor.

(I can get a mapping of a raw buffer to a non complex matrix map to work.  It seems the addition of the complex aspect is introducing issues for the direct map.  This page was great but didn't have a n example for my specific issue. https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialMapClass.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, As normal just as I posted the question I tried a new option which worked.  Curious if there is a better solution out there...

```
 // my types
 typedef Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<uint16_t>, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>
  MyMatrixXci;
  typedef Eigen::Map<MyMatrixXci> MyMapMatrixXci;

 // some consts
 const size_t rows = 3;
 const size_t cols = 4;

 // fake some raw data. (2 below is for complex real,imag)
 uint8_t *raw = new uint8_t[rows * cols * sizeof(uint16_t) * 2];
 for (size_t i = 0; i < rows * cols * 2; ++i) {
     raw[i * 2] = i;
 }

 // answer
 const MyMapMatrixXci mat(
     reinterpret_cast<std::complex<uint16_t> *>(raw),
     rows,
     cols);

 // Verify answer
 std::cout << mat << std::endl;
```

This seems to match my expected answer...

```
 (0,1)   (6,7) (12,13) (18,19)
 (2,3)   (8,9) (14,15) (20,21)
 (4,5) (10,11) (16,17) (22,23)
```

Comment: That is basically how to do it. Just in case your input data is `const`, you need to use `Eigen::Map<MyMatrixXci const>` and `reinterpret_cast<std::complex<uint16_t> const*>`. Or `auto mat = MyMatrixXci::Map(reinterpret_cast<std::complex<uint16_t> const *>(raw), rows, cols)` (instead of assigning it to `auto mat` this can also be used directly inside expressions).

Comment: Also, maybe make yourself some `typedef` for `std::complex<uint16_t>` for convenience.